# how to set http protocol version for request in AFNetworking library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, http, afnetworking

I have a server that serves with http2 and http/1.1 when I make requests to server in my iOS app  it always make the requests using http2, I've changed the http version in the android app using okhttp like this:

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setWriteTimeout(WRITE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        List<Protocol> protocols = new ArrayList<>();
        protocols.add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);
        okHttpClient.setProtocols(protocols);
```

I wonder if exists something like that in AFNetworking library.

Comment: hey @irvin Chan, any luck with that?

Comment: hey , nothing for now :/.